# Multiple elements using clip-path in Raphael

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, clip

All, We have a shape made of paths (lets call this parent), on which a user can drag & drop different objs.

We are using clip-path to hide the obj., i.e. if it goes beyond the boundary of the parent shape, it gets hidden.

Inside the parent shape, user can drag & drop obj. We fill these obj. with images. If the images are bigger than the obj. then part of the image outside the obj. boundary is also hidden (clip-rect of Raphael).

Unfortunately, Raphael doesnot appear to like multiple clip-path & we get a conflict, i.e. the obj. with image inside get its clip-path functionality overwritten by the parent shape clip-path; the images become visible outside the boundary of the obj.

EDIT: Here is an illustration of what we want to do. Hope this further explains via illustration.[image]

Comment: Can you use clip-rect for the yellow rect and make the big black background a donut hole? That way you use clip-rect once?

Comment: @Chasbeen, thanks however it wont work in our web app. Im replying below to your answer in detail.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have a partial solution for this..
If you find it relevant please send me feedback on my website

Go to the index on my website and look at the "Thought Cloud"
It consists of a large path area with the "Thought cloud" cutting a hole through the larger path area.

My site is at

http://www.irunmywebsite.com/

/*UPDATE 8TH April 2013*/
Multiple clip path is just as possible (Uses the same principal) as single clip path in Raphael
Single clip path Example
[Donut hole](http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?q=donutholes)
Multiple clip path Example
[Here we clip 9 images twice! The clip path overlay makes the images have rounded corners](http://www.irunmywebsite.com/visualdesign/ffc.php)
I hope this helps, formatting this reply on IPod so spelling and other things maybe a bit off..

Comment: Thank you @chasbeen, we have been a fan of your site (when it was SVG) & learnt a lot then. We are looking at 'Thought Cloud', however, if Im reading this right, it appears to be a simple clip-path hiding area outside the clip-path. I am going to post a drawing to further illustration on original post.

Comment: It is the same principle as this: www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?v=2&q=donutholes except the shape in the middle is just a circle. Make sure that the inner shape has a path definition going in the correct direction

Comment: Now I understand what you mean by donut hole. Unfortunately, we did consider it & it wont work. In our application the user can alter the items on display so they can easily extend an item outside the donut shape. Please see this image as example of what can happen. 
http://imgur.com/H8IYF